# Assigning class to variable with "using"

Tags: c#, using

Simple question that I can't seem to wrap my head around. Say I want to save time/space when working with commonly used `System` classes and I want to assign an entire class/subclass such as `System.Threading.Thread` to a variable so that I can use the shortened `Variable.ThreadMethod()` whenever I want to use a method of the Thread class.

I though it was done with the following:

```
using test = System.Threading.Thread;
```

However this throws the `"Invalid token 'using' in class, struct or interface declaration."`
The context of what I am trying to do is the following:

```
    using test = System.Threading.Thread;
    public void Method()
    {
       test.Sleep(1000); //Same as System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: are you mixing [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) with [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: @Habib: No, he isn't.

Comment: BTW, that isn't a variable.

Comment: BTW, the usual (idiomatic) way of doing this is to have `using System.Threading;` and then just `Thread.Sleep(1000);`, or to spell it out in full if necessary. Using `using` like this is rare, and I wouldn't recommend it (characters are cheap, confusion is not).

Answer (score 4):

`using` directives can only appear at the top of the file or namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the `using` on top of your c# file before declaring a `class`.

This works:

```
using test = System.Threading.Thread;

namespace Y
{
    public class X
    {
        public void Method()
        {
           test.Sleep(1000); //Same as System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your using with the others using:

```
using test = System.Threading.Thread;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        test.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```